# How to implement a sliding window in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have created a sliding window algorithm using numpy that slides over a wav audio file and feeds slices of it to my NN in tensorflow, which detects features in the audio slices. Once tensorflow does its thing, it returns its output to numpy land, where I reassemble the slices into an array of predictions that match each sample position of the original file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import nn

def slide_predict(layers, X, modelPath):
    output = None

    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels = layers

        X_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, input_layer_size), name='X')
        Theta1 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size), name='Theta1')
        bias1 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(hidden_layer_size, 1), name='bias1')
        Theta2 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(hidden_layer_size, num_labels), name='Theta2')
        bias2 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(num_labels, 1), name='bias2')
        hypothesis = nn.forward_prop(X_placeholder, Theta1, bias1, Theta2, bias2)

        sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        saver.restore(sess, modelPath)

        window_size = layers[0]

        pad_amount = (window_size * 2) - (X.shape[0] % window_size)
        X = np.pad(X, (pad_amount, 0), 'constant')

        for w in range(window_size):
            start = w
            end = -window_size + w
            X_shifted = X[start:end]
            X_matrix = X_shifted.reshape((-1, window_size))

            prediction = sess.run(hypothesis, feed_dict={X_placeholder: X_matrix})

            output = prediction if (output is None) else np.hstack((output, prediction))

        sess.close()

    output.shape = (X.size, -1)

    return output
```

Unfortunately, this algorithm is quite slow. I placed some logs along the way and by far the slowest portion is the part where I actually run my tensorflow graph. This could be due to the actual tensorflow calculations being slow (if so, I'm probably just SOL), but I am wondering if a large part of the slowness isn't because I am transferring large audio files repeatedly back and forth in and out of tensorflow. So my questions are:

1) Is feeding a placeholder repeatedly like this going to be noticeably slower than feeding it once and calculating the values for `X` inside tensorflow?

2) If yes, whats the best way to implement a sliding window algorithm inside tensorflow to do this calculation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first issue is that your algorithm is has quadratic time complexity in `window_size`, because of calling `np.hstack()` in each iteration to build the `output` array, which copies both the current values of `output` and `prediction` into a new array:

```
for w in range(window_size):
    # ...
    output = prediction if (output is None) else np.hstack((output, prediction))
```

Instead of calling `np.hstack()` in every iteration, it would be more efficient to build a Python list of the `prediction` arrays, and call `np.hstack()` on them once, after the loop terminates:

```
output_list = []
for w in range(window_size):
    # ...
    prediction = sess.run(...)
    output_list.append(prediction)
output = np.hstack(output_list)
```

The second issue is that feeding large values to TensorFlow can be inefficient, if the amount of computation in the `sess.run()` call is small, because those values are (currently) copied into C++ (and the results are copied out. One useful strategy for this is to try and move the sliding window loop into the TensorFlow graph, using the [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/functional_ops/higher_order_operators#map_fn) construct. For example, you could restructure your program as follows:

```
# NOTE: If you call this function often, you may want to (i) move the `np.pad()`
# into the graph as `tf.pad()`, and (ii) replace `X_t` with a placeholder.
X = np.pad(X, (pad_amount, 0), 'constant')
X_t  = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)

def window_func(w):
    start = w
    end = w - window_size
    X_matrix = tf.reshape(X_t[start:end], (-1, window_size))
    return nn.forward_prop(X_matrix, Theta1, bias1, Theta2, bias2)

output_t = tf.map_fn(window_func, tf.range(window_size))
# ...
output = sess.run(output_t)
```

Comment: Does tf.map_fn have a GPU implementation? Provided the CNN is on the GPU using map_fn will be effective only if it has a GPU kernel registered right?

Comment: Yes, `tf.map_fn()` will work with a function that uses the GPU. (The `tf.range()` and the control flow will probably execute on the CPU, but it will dispatch the CNN to the GPU.)

Comment: Doh, thank you! That stacking method of mine was dumb. Do you happen to know if slicing a tensor like that (`X_t[start:end]`) is copying values or just shifting the view over them? That could be another source of slowness if im copying things every time. It would be great if there was a way to just increment a pointer over that array

Comment: Glad to help! The slicing operator can sometimes avoid making a copy… I think the main requirement is that the resulting slice be 32-byte aligned (because many of the operator implementations require that) and they might need to be dense (which should be fine if you're slicing a vector).